# Metrization of projective manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, projective-geometry

A modern take on Hilbert's fourth problem could be as follows:

*Given a manifold $M$ with a flat projective structure (i.e., a $(PGL(n+1),\mathbb{RP}^n)$-structure), find all metrics for which the lines of the structure are geodesics.*

The word *metric* here can be taken to mean continuous symmetric or asymmetric distance function, $C^1$ Finsler metric, or $C^2$ Finsler metric. The answers differ with the regularity of the metric. Stated in this way, the first question is whether such a metric even exists: what projective manifolds can be *metrized*? Indeed, not all of them can be: in some there are pairs of points that are not joined by any single line, in others some homotopy classes of curves are not represented by closed lines, and for most I have no idea. We can manipulate a  classic result of Beltrami to say that *the only projective manifolds that can be metrized by Riemann metrics are spaces that can be metrized as Riemannian manifolds of constant curvature*. Lately I've been wondering whether there is a **global** Finsler version of this result:

**Question.** *Given a closed manifold $M$ with a $C^2$ Finsler metric whose geodesics define a projective structure on $M$, is there a $C^2$ Riemannian metric with the same unparametrized geodesics?*

In other words, *are compact space forms, seen as compact projective manifolds, the only ones that can be metrized by $C^2$ Finsler metrics?*

For $C^1$ metrics the answer is no: there are plenty of convex projective structures on compact manifolds and these carry the Hilbert metric, which is a $C^1$ Finsler metric (see Y. Benoist's work on divisible convex bodies) .

I realize the question is research project or a reference request, but I would appreciate any pertinent comment or remark.